# MYSQL запрос на вывод разницы строк двух таблиц и удалением дубликатов полей с учётом id строки

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli

На stackoverflow есть множество примеров, которые позволяют получить разницу строк двух таблиц, но они не учитывают дубликаты, если я в случае повторения хочу получить пустое поле. Подходящего примера я не нашёл.
Есть запрос к примеру:

```
SELECT Id, username FROM table1
WHERE (Id, username) NOT IN (SELECT Id, username FROM table2)
```

который выведет строки из table1, которых нету в table2 с учётом id, но мне нужно чтобы в случае повтора поля строки, запрос выводил пустое поле, чтобы сравнивать несколько столбцов.

Пример
Таблица 1

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  | Jhon  | Zero
2  | Test  | First
3  | Mike  | Second
4  | James | Third
5  | Ivan  | Fourth
6  | Jhon  | Zero
```

Таблица 2

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  | Jhon  | Test0
2  | JACK  | First
3  | MIKE  | Second3
4  | Jame  | Third4
5  | Evan  | Fourth
6  | Jhon  | Zero
```

Результат вывода SELECT

```
id |  name | surname
--------------------
1  |       | Zero
2  | Test  | 
3  | Mike  | Second
4  | James | Third
5  | Ivan  | 
6  |       |
```

Т.е. мне нужно, чтобы при выводе строк дубликаты полей были равны Null - пустому значению, а также всё с учётом регистра букв. Напишите, пожалуйста, как это сделать, возможно ли вообще это с mysql.

Comment: простой join двух таблиц по id. Вместо каждого поля конструкцию `if(t1.name=t2.name, NULL, t1.name) as name`

Comment: Спасибо, а можно подробнее запрос целиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       NULLIF(t1.name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, t2.name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin) name, 
       NULLIF(t1.surname COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, t2.surname COLLATE utf8mb4_bin) surname
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
-- удалить полностью совпадающие записи
-- HAVING COALESCE(name, surname) IS NOT NULL
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a070caef91d72484a812b5fe8bbe8f43)

Comment: этот запрос не делает поле пустым в случае повторения

Comment: либо же у меня он как-то отображается неправильно, но это не то, что я хотел

Comment: @YAMER1 Да, верно. Join по всем полям уберёт полностью правую запись же... Откорректировал запрос.

Comment: Ваш ответ работает с utf8_bin. Только иногда бывает, что пустую строку выводит, если нету изменений. Можно сделать дополнительное условие, чтобы такую строку не показывало?

Comment: @YAMER1 *иногда бывает, что пустую строку выводит, если нету изменений* ??? В Вашем же примере я вижу именно такую строку. ID=6 которая. Ок, добавил.

Comment: Да, всё, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ответили на англоязычном форуме

```
SELECT t1.id,
       CASE WHEN t1.name != t2.name THEN t1.name END AS name,
       CASE WHEN t1.surname != t2.surname THEN t1.surname END AS surname
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Если поля `name` и `surname` не объявлены с регистрозависимым COLLATION - результат будет неверным. Чтобы не зависеть от структуры, следует при сравнении задавать COLLATION явно (см., как это сделано в моём ответе). Про возможность, что и charset различается, вообще молчу...

Comment: там ответ был SELECT t1.id,
       CASE WHEN t1.name COLLATE latin1_general_cs != t2.name COLLATE latin1_general_cs THEN t1.name END AS name,
       CASE WHEN t1.surname COLLATE latin1_general_cs != t2.surname THEN t1.surname COLLATE latin1_general_cs END AS surname
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

Comment: у меня с latin1_general_cs не работало, поэтому не стал писать, поменял на utf8_bin как было написано в одном из вопросов, всё заработало